# call number from database with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have form in android studio with SQLite, by this form I can add, update and delete .. now I want to add a new button for calling by id .

form example when I put number 3 in the column and click call button should select number where id=id and call him direct.

I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: Select * by id from table name .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you can use a "SELECT * FROM [Table_Name] WHERE ID = [Column_Text]"

Hope this helps ./